# asyncio - open connection using specific interface

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

I'm trying to move across some code to use asyncio (for various reasons). In my existing code I create a socket which I `bind()` to a specific interface to ensure the TCP connection is made on that interface:

```
_TCP_Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
_TCP_Socket.bind(('169.254.6.1', 13000)) # All data sent from this IP, Port (i.e using the interface that has this IP)
_TCP_Socket.connect(('169.254.10.123, 13000))
```

The above works but how do I achieve the same in asyncio? i.e. how do I select the interface to send from? With `asyncio.open_connection()` there is no `bind()` as such.

So, do I pass it a socket? i.e. create a socket as before which is bound to the interface I want to send from and then call `open_connection`?

```
reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('169.254.10.123', 13000, sock=_TCP_Socket) # Use _TCP_Socket created earlier?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documenation [says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) that `asyncio.open_connection` has named parameter `local_addr`, whose description can be found in the [create_connection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_connection) description:

> if given, is a `(local_host, local_port)` tuple used to bind the socket to locally.

Because `open_connection` is a wrapper for `create_connection` and docs contains following sentence:

> The rest of the arguments are passed directly to loop.create_connection().

Comment: I couldn't see in the docs where it described ```local_addr``` - where did you find that info?

Comment: Updated answer.